# Yarn install, not able to install all dependencies in my project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, next.js, yarnpkg

I cloned a project from `gitlab` and tried to install the dependencies using `yarn install` command. But there are few dependencies yarn is not able to install. It is showing this message `info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...`

I tried to install using `npm` but couldn't do with that even.
deleted `package.lock.json`, didn't work

It is a next.js based project

Here is the console snap
[image]

Comment: The problem is either with your firewall, network, or the remote server.

Comment: I tried it on different network but still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

try disabling proxy/firewall and try again

Comment: Yes, my proxy was set. So I turned it off. but the problem still persists